# How to use select using HQL with find function grails (GORM)?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, hql, grails-orm

I am new to grails and learning by its documentation available online.

one thing which confused me while reading about  [find()](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/find.html) function.

```
Book.find(String query) // pass the HQL, However there are various overloaded variants.
```

Now if I use this `find()` function like this.

```
Category.find("from Category as cat where cat.id = ? ", [5L]) //result is fine.
```

My Category Class

```
class Category {

    String title;
    String description
    String image
    static constraints = {
        title blank: false, nullable: false
        description blank: true, nullable: true
    }
}
```

but if I tried this HQL query

```
 Category.find("select  cat.description from Category as cat where cat.id = ? ", [5L])
//or this query.
 Category.find("select description from Category as cat where cat.id = ? ", [5L])
```

it raise an exception :-

```
Invalid query [select  cat.description from Category as cat where cat.id = ? ] for domain class [class com.ecommerce.domain.Category]. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Invalid query [select  cat.description from Category as cat where cat.id = ? ] for domain class [class com.ecommerce.domain.Category]
```

so, if any problem with my HQL please comment.....

or 
you may answer how to use select statement with `find(String query)`??

Comment: Have you tried `findAll()`?

Answer (score 1):

For a single result:

```
Category.find("from Category cat where cat.id = ?", [5L])?.description
```

Or for multiples:

```
Category.find("from Category cat where cat.id = ?", [5L]).collect{ it.description }
```

Comment: However ... This was not  a answer as I was expecting.. but this answer deserves one up-vote...